# Find the minium paranthese to be added at start or end of a parantheses string to make it balance

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Need to balance a parentheses by adding minimum required parentheses at the start or end.
Example-
If **I = "(()(())"** then
**R = [0,1]**

I created a solution like

```js
function bPar(s){
    let stack1 = [];
    let result = [0,0];

    s.split("").forEach(x=>{
        if(x==="("){
            stack1.push("(");
        }else if(x===")"){
            if(stack1[stack1.length-1]==="("){
                stack1.pop();
            }else{
                stack1.push(")")
            }
        }
    })

    stack1.forEach(x=>{
        if(x=="("){
            result[1]=result[1]+1;
        }else if(x==")"){
            result[0]=result[0]+1;
        }
    })
    return result;
}

console.log(bPar("(()(())"));
```

But I think the time complexity is higher. Is their any better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a stack array, you could keep track of the *number* of currently open parentheses. If you come across a `)` while that number is 0, add a number to the number of additional required `(`s:

```js
function bPar(s){
  let additionalOpensNeededAtBegin = 0;
  let openCount = 0;
  for (const char of s) {
    if (char === '(') openCount++;
    else {
      if (openCount === 0) additionalOpensNeededAtBegin++;
      else openCount--;
    }
  }
  return [additionalOpensNeededAtBegin, openCount];
}

console.log(bPar("(()(())"));
console.log(bPar("((((("));
console.log(bPar(")))))"));
console.log(bPar(")(((("));
console.log(bPar("))))("));
console.log(bPar("(())"));
```